# What is the connect timeout for a socket on linux

Tags: networking, sockets, ubuntu

I have a programming running on linux ubuntu which tries to connect to a server port using TCP.
Can you please tell me how can I find out that is timeout value for a client socket connecting to a server socket for ubuntu?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The best, portable solution is to use your own timeout to be sure you can rely on a known value :

1) before `connect()`ing, set the client socket to be non-blocking. Use `ioctl()` and the `FIONBIO` flag or `fcntl()` and `O_NONBLOCK` flags. Under Win32, use `ioctlsocket()` and `FIONBIO` flag.

2) `connect()` to the remote peer : if `connect()` succeed, all right, you are connected.

3)  However if `connect()` returns -1 and set `errno` to `EINPROGRESS` (`WSAEWOULDBLOCK` under Win32), just `select()` the socket descriptor for writing with your own timeout.

Answer (score 1):

I'd start by looking at the `getsockopt(3)` man page (**SO_RCVTIMEO**).  However I'm sure there's more to your question than that.

Comment: Yeah, I have looked at that, but SO_RCVTIMEO and SO_SENDTIMEO is for send(), recv() function calls? not connect(). Is that right?